# Find all files that are shared in Google Drive

Tags: google-drive, sharing

Is there an easy way to find all files in Google Drive that you have shared with anyone? What about if you want to find all files in Google Drive you have shared with a particular person?

Answer (score 0):

Shared with a particular person is possible. Type in searchbox:

```
to:someone@gmail.com
```

Or use the little triangle in the right of the seachbox to insert fields.